# get data from sql and show on specific location

Tags: php, sql

I m using the following query to get data from sql :

```
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
  {
  $url = ''.$row['a'].'&nbsp;'.$row['b'].'&nbsp;'.$row['c'].'&nbsp;'.$row['d'].'<br>';
  }
```

now i want to do replace {URL} (that is writen in html file ) with data from sql

```
$mtheme = str_replace("{URL}",$url,$mtheme);
```

echo $mtheme;

the problem i that it shows only last row

Comment: @Forlan07 sorry, I rejected your edit! It looked weird in the accept reject panel, maybe it was correct and not your fault!

Answer (score 0):

```
$url .= ''.$row['a'].'&nbsp;'.$row['b'].'&nbsp;'.$row['c'].'&nbsp;'.$row['d'].'<br>';
```

Comment: I can't tell if what cute really wants to do is concatenate all the $row's into $url, but if he does, this looks right

Comment: NOT WORKING       $url .= ''.$row['a'].'&nbsp;'.$row['b'].'&nbsp;'.$row['c'].'&nbsp;'.$row['d'].'<br>';

Comment: print $url after while loop and check its content

Comment: add var_dump($url); after while loop and check if $url is not empty